# How To Use Loop IN Sp or UDF Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database

i am trying to pass id to Sp then it will first get id's against it and then get data against those id using SP or by using UDF as i trying it by

```
select RequestFrom from UserReqest where RequestTo=10 and IsApprove=0

select * from user where user_ID= (i have to use all five id's here ?)
```

Hopes for your suggestions

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [IN operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx) in SQL that does what you want:

```
select * 
from user 
where user_ID in (select RequestFrom 
                    from UserReqest 
                    where RequestTo=10 
                      and IsApprove=0)
```